# JQuery Plugin and Browserify

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, module, browserify

I am trying to use a JQuery plugin with Browserify. Here is relevant section of my package.json file where I define the plugin's dependency on JQuery:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      [
        "node-underscorify",
        {
          "extensions": [
            "tpl"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "plugin": "./src/static/js/plugin.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "plugin": {
      "exports": "plugin",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:jQuery"
      ]
    }
  },
```

JQuery was pulled in via NPM and is available without any problem within my Browserify modules:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

I access the JQuery plugin using:

```
require('plugin');
```

When I hit the line that calls a method on the JQuery plugin, it blows up:

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown();  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong. Thank you very much in advance.

**Edited To Account for JMM's Question - Plugin Definition Code**

```
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      // AMD. Register as an anonymous module depending on jQuery.
      define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    //Support for Atom/CommonJS - Not Tested TODO
    module.exports = factory;
  } else {
      // No AMD. Register plugin with global jQuery object.
      factory(jQuery);
  }
}(function ($) {

  $.fn.dropdown = function(options) {}

}
```

Comment: The plugin probably isn't getting access to the jQuery object. Is it your own plugin or someone else's? You'd likely need to show the plugin definition code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
require('plugin')($);
```